# AWS COGNITO: How to implement Post Confirmation Trigger which works only after SignupConfirmation not after ForgotPassword/ResetPassword Confirmation

Tags: node.js, angular, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Someone can please tell me, that how can send this mail after the **Post Confirmation** of Signup only. This code is sending mail after every confirmation whether it is forget password/reset password or Signup.

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

var ses = new aws.SES();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event);

    if (event.request.userAttributes.email) {
            sendEmail(event.request.userAttributes.email, "Congratulations " + event.userName + ", you have been confirmed: ", function(status) {

            // Return to Amazon Cognito
            callback(null, event);
        });
    } else {
        // Nothing to do, the user's email ID is unknown
        callback(null, event);
    }
};

function sendEmail(to, body, completedCallback) {
    var eParams = {
        Destination: {
            ToAddresses: [to]
        },
        Message: {
            Body: {
                Text: {
                    Data: body
                }
            },
            Subject: {
                Data: "Cognito Identity Provider registration completed"
            }
        },

        // Replace source_email with your SES validated email address
        Source: "<source_email>"
    };

    var email = ses.sendEmail(eParams, function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("===EMAIL SENT===");
        }
        completedCallback('Email sent');
    });
    console.log("EMAIL CODE END");
};
```

Answer (score 10):

You can check `triggerSource` attribute of the `event` object.

Post Confirmation of Signup event will have trigger source is `PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp`

Your handle function will look like this:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(event);

  if (
    event.request.userAttributes.email
    && event.triggerSource === "PostConfirmation_ConfirmSignUp") {
    sendEmail(event.request.userAttributes.email, "Congratulations " + event.userName + ", you have been confirmed: ", function (status) {

      // Return to Amazon Cognito
      callback(null, event);
    });
  } else {
    // Nothing to do, the user's email ID is unknown
    callback(null, event);
  }
};
```

Reference: [User Pool Lambda Trigger Sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-trigger-sources)